# Dadata.ru API возвращает неполные данные

Tags: php, api

кто работал с API dadata.ru?
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, имеется PHP код:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'query' => '6449013711'
];
$options = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => [
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Authorization: Token 939c7bfb4d6a1021a06a7856623858ac7a6fc89c'
        ],
        'content' => json_encode($data)
    ]
];
$builder = stream_context_create($options);
$document = file_get_contents('https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/findById/party', false, $builder);
$output = json_decode($document);
var_dump($output);
```

Который возвращает массив данных (неполный), например в ответе нет данных о документации.
НО, console.log() данных на странице https://dadata.ru/suggestions/usage/#party
Возвращает полные данные, включая документацию и т.д.
Кто сталкивался с этой проблемой? Всем спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Документация, лицензии и некоторые другие поля возвращаются в методе "[Организация по ИНН](https://dadata.ru/api/find-party/)" в тарифе "[Всё включено](https://dadata.ru/suggestions/#pricing)". На демо-форме показан пример данных, которые можно получить от Дадаты.

Если у вас есть вопросы по сервису их всегда можно задать в [службе поддержки](https://dadata.userecho.com/knowledge-bases/4-baza-znanij).